Creating HUD like that of Mission planner
I'm working on a project to simulate a HUD (Head-Up Display) using tkinter and mavutil to receive telemetry data from a flight controller. However, the simulation doesn't match what I see in Mission Planner, a ground control software commonly used in drone operations.
Here's a summary of my setup:
I'm using Python with tkinter for the GUI.
Telemetry data is received from the flight controller using mavutil.
I've implemented functions to update and draw various elements on the HUD, including airspeed, altitude, and attitude indicators.
Despite these efforts, the simulation in my tkinter-based HUD doesn't match what's displayed in Mission Planner. I've considered factors like data interpretation, coordinate systems, and scaling, but I haven't been able to identify the exact cause of the discrepancy.
What could be causing this mismatch between my tkinter-based HUD simulation and what's shown in Mission Planner? Are there any specific considerations or adjustments I should make to better align the simulation with Mission Planner?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
here is my code:
import tkinter as tk
from pymavlink import mavutil
import math

class HUD:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("HUD Example")

        # Create a canvas to draw the HUD
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500, bg='white')
        self.canvas.pack()

        # initializing mavlink connection
        self.the_connection = mavutil.mavlink_connection('tcp:127.0.0.1:5762')
        self.the_connection.wait_heartbeat()
        print("Heartbeat from system (system %u component %u)" % (self.the_connection.target_system, self.the_connection.target_component))

        # Initial airspeed and altitude values
        self.airspeed = 0  # Example airspeed value
        self.altitude = 0  # Example altitude value
        self.altitude_offset = 0
        self.pitch = 0
        self.bank_angle = 0

        # Draw the HUD
        self.draw_hud()

        # take off
        # self.take_off()
        
        self.root.after(15 , self.update)
    
    def draw_hud(self):
        self.canvas.delete("all")  # Clear previous drawings

        # Draw blue background
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 500, 250, fill="Blue")  # Light Blue
        # Draw green background
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 250, 500, 500, fill="#B7EB8F")  # Light Green

        # Draw Airspeed scale on the left
        self.draw_airspeed_scale(42, 250)

        # Draw Altitude scale on the right
        self.draw_altitude_scale(460, 250)

        # Draw bank angle
        self.draw_bank_angle_indicator(250 , 200 , 100 , self.bank_angle)

        # Draw attitude scale
        self.draw_attitude_scale(250, 250, 200, 150, self.pitch, self.bank_angle)

    def draw_airspeed_scale(self, x, y_center):
        # Draw the background colors
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(x-40, y_center-150, x+40, y_center, fill="#A6CAF0", outline="white",width=3)  # Light Blue
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(x-40, y_center, x+40, y_center+150, fill="#B7EB8F", outline="white",width=3)  # Light Green

        # Draw the scale markings and labels
        for i in range(-10, 11, 5):
            y = y_center - i * 15
            self.canvas.create_line(x-20, y, x+40, y, width=2 , fill= "white")
            self.canvas.create_text(x+40, y, text=str(i), font=("Arial", 12))

        # Draw the airspeed indicator
        indicator_y = y_center - self.airspeed * 15
        self.canvas.create_polygon(
            x-35, indicator_y - 15,  # Top-left point
            x+35, indicator_y - 15,  # Top-right point
            x+45, indicator_y,  # Middle-right point
            x+35, indicator_y + 15,  # Bottom-right point
            x-35, indicator_y + 15,  # Bottom-left point
            fill="black"
        )
        self.canvas.create_text(x-5, indicator_y, text=f"{self.airspeed:.1f} m/s", fill="white", font=("Arial", 10))

    def draw_altitude_scale(self, x, y_center):
        # Draw the background colors
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(x-40, y_center-150, x+40, y_center, fill="#A6CAF0",outline="white",width=3)  # Light Blue
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(x-40, y_center, x+40, y_center+150, fill="#B7EB8F",outline="white",width=3)  # Light Green

        # Draw the scale markings and labels
        for i in range(-10, 11, 5):
            y = y_center - i * 15
            self.canvas.create_line(x-40, y, x+20, y, width=2 , fill= "white")
            self.canvas.create_text(x-40, y, text=str(i*100), font=("Arial", 12))

        # Draw the altitude indicator
        indicator_y = y_center - (self.altitude / 100) * 15
        self.canvas.create_polygon(
            x+35, indicator_y - 15,  # Top-left point
            x-35, indicator_y - 15,  # Top-right point
            x-45, indicator_y,  # Middle-right point
            x-35, indicator_y + 15,  # Bottom-right point
            x+35, indicator_y + 15,  # Bottom-left point
            fill="black"
        )
        self.canvas.create_text(x+5, indicator_y, text=f"{self.altitude:.1f} ft", fill="white", font=("Arial", 10))
    
    def draw_bank_angle_indicator(self, x_center, y_center, radius , roll):
        # Draw the semicircular scale facing downwards

        roll_rad = math.radians(roll)
        cos_roll = math.cos(roll_rad)
        sin_roll = math.sin(roll_rad)

        def rotate_point(x, y, ox, oy, cos_theta, sin_theta):
            x_new = ox + cos_theta * (x - ox) - sin_theta * (y - oy)
            y_new = oy + sin_theta * (x - ox) + cos_theta * (y - oy)
            return x_new, y_new

        # Arc parameters
        large_radius = radius * 1.35
        arc_points = []
        for angle in range(17, 162, 1):
            angle_rad = math.radians(angle)
            x = x_center -large_radius * math.cos(angle_rad)
            y = y_center -large_radius * math.sin(angle_rad)
            x_rot, y_rot = rotate_point(x, y, x_center, y_center, cos_roll, sin_roll)
            arc_points.append((x_rot, y_rot))

        # Draw the rotated arc
        for i in range(len(arc_points) - 1):
            self.canvas.create_line(arc_points[i][0], arc_points[i][1], arc_points[i + 1][0], arc_points[i + 1][1], fill="white", width=2)

        # Draw the scale markings and labels
        for angle in range(-60, 61, 10):
            angle_rad = math.radians(angle)
            x_start = x_center + large_radius * math.sin(angle_rad)
            y_start = y_center - large_radius * math.cos(angle_rad)
            x_end = x_center + (large_radius + 10) * math.sin(angle_rad)
            y_end = y_center - (large_radius + 10) * math.cos(angle_rad)

            x_start_rot, y_start_rot = rotate_point(x_start, y_start, x_center, y_center, cos_roll, sin_roll)
            x_end_rot, y_end_rot = rotate_point(x_end, y_end, x_center, y_center, cos_roll, sin_roll)

            self.canvas.create_line(x_start_rot, y_start_rot, x_end_rot, y_end_rot, fill="white", width=2)

            x_text = x_center + (large_radius + 25) * math.sin(angle_rad)
            y_text = y_center - (large_radius + 25) * math.cos(angle_rad)
            x_text_rot, y_text_rot = rotate_point(x_text, y_text, x_center, y_center, cos_roll, sin_roll)

            self.canvas.create_text(x_text_rot, y_text_rot, text=str(abs(angle)), font=("Arial", 12), fill="white")


            self.canvas.create_polygon(
                x_center, y_center - large_radius - 10,
                x_center - 10, y_center - large_radius + 5,
                x_center + 10, y_center - large_radius + 5,
                fill="red"
            )
    
    def draw_attitude_scale(self, x_center, y_center, width, height, pitch, roll):
    # Rotate canvas for roll
        # self.canvas.create_rectangle(
        #     x_center - width // 2, y_center - height // 2,
        #     x_center + width // 2, y_center + height // 2,
        #     outline='', fill='#A6CAF0'
        # )

        pitch_offset = pitch * 5  # Adjust the multiplier to scale the pitch properly

        # Draw horizon line
        horizon_y = y_center + pitch_offset
        horizon_start_x = x_center - width // 2
        horizon_end_x = x_center + width // 2

        # Apply rotation for roll
        roll_rad = math.radians(roll)
        cos_roll = math.cos(roll_rad)
        sin_roll = math.sin(roll_rad)

        def rotate_point(x, y, ox, oy, cos_theta, sin_theta):
            # Rotate (x, y) around (ox, oy) by theta
            x_new = ox + cos_theta * (x - ox) - sin_theta * (y - oy)
            y_new = oy + sin_theta * (x - ox) + cos_theta * (y - oy)
            return x_new, y_new

        # Calculate new positions for horizon line ends
        horizon_start_x_rot, horizon_y_rot = rotate_point(horizon_start_x, horizon_y, x_center, y_center, cos_roll, sin_roll)
        horizon_end_x_rot, horizon_end_y_rot = rotate_point(horizon_end_x, horizon_y, x_center, y_center, cos_roll, sin_roll)

        self.canvas.create_line(
            horizon_start_x_rot, horizon_y_rot,
            horizon_end_x_rot, horizon_end_y_rot,
            fill="red", width=3
        )

        # Draw pitch markings
        for i in range(-20, 21, 5):
            if i == 0:
                continue
            line_length = 40 if i % 2 == 0 else 80  # Alternating shorter and longer lines
            line_y = horizon_y + (i*5)
            line_start_x = x_center - line_length
            line_end_x = x_center + line_length

            # Rotate the line endpoints
            line_start_x_rot, line_start_y_rot = rotate_point(line_start_x, line_y, x_center, y_center, cos_roll, sin_roll)
            line_end_x_rot, line_end_y_rot = rotate_point(line_end_x, line_y, x_center, y_center, cos_roll, sin_roll)

            self.canvas.create_line(
                line_start_x_rot, line_start_y_rot,
                line_end_x_rot, line_end_y_rot,
                fill="white", width=3
            )


    def update_airspeed(self, airspeed):
        self.airspeed = airspeed
        self.draw_hud()

    def update_altitude(self, altitude):
        self.altitude = altitude
        self.draw_hud()
    
    def update_attitude_scale(self, pitch , roll):
        self.pitch = pitch
        self.bank_angle = roll
        self.draw_hud()

    # def take_off(self):
        #     self.the_connection.mav.command_long_send(
        #     self.the_connection.target_system, 
        #     self.the_connection.target_component, 
        #     mavutil.mavlink.MAV_CMD_COMPONENT_ARM_DISARM, 
        #     0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        # # for taking off
        #     self.the_connection.mav.command_long_send(
        #     self.the_connection.target_system, 
        #     self.the_connection.target_component, 
        #     mavutil.mavlink.MAV_CMD_NAV_TAKEOFF, 
        #     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10)

    def update(self):

        msg = self.the_connection.recv_msg()
        if msg:
            if msg.get_type() == 'VFR_HUD':
                self.update_airspeed(msg.airspeed)
                self.update_altitude(msg.alt)
            elif msg.get_type() == 'ATTITUDE':
                self.pitch = math.degrees(msg.pitch)
                self.roll = math.degrees(msg.roll)
                self.update_attitude_scale(self.pitch , self.roll)
             

        self.root.after(15 , self.update)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.config(padx= 20 , pady= 20)
    hud = HUD(root)
    root.mainloop()


heads up display
In attempting to rotate the canvas to simulate the HUD display similar to Mission Planner, I initially experimented with altering the transformation matrix of the canvas. I explored various methods to achieve rotation, including using built-in tkinter functions and custom rotation calculations.
Additionally, to replicate the visual aesthetics of Mission Planner, I made adjustments to the colors used in the HUD elements. I experimented with different color schemes and contrasts, trying to match those observed in Mission Planner's interface.
Despite these efforts, I encountered challenges in accurately aligning the simulation with Mission Planner. The rotation of the canvas didn't produce the expected results, and the color adjustments didn't fully replicate the visual appearance of Mission Planner's HUD.
Specifically, I attempted to:
Canvas Rotation: Tried adjusting the canvas rotation using methods such as canvas.rotate() or manually modifying the transformation matrix. However, I couldn't achieve the desired rotation effect.
Color Adjustments: Experimented with various color palettes and shades to match Mission Planner's HUD interface. Although I made some progress, the colors still didn't closely resemble those in Mission Planner.
Despite these efforts, the simulation doesn't accurately reflect the HUD display observed in Mission Planner. I'm seeking guidance on alternative approaches or potential adjustments to better align the simulation with Mission Planner's HUD.
